# TD Ameritrade API Options Chains Getting wrong values for Greeks (Delta,Vega....) -999

Tags: python, json, ameritrade

Calling the TD Ameritrade API for Get Options Chains at https://developer.tdameritrade.com/option-chains/apis/get/marketdata/chains#, I keep getting strange -999 values for the greeks here is a snippet. I have tried both ANALYTICAL and SINGLE for strategy. This is what I get back, any ideas what I am doing wrong ? :

- "volatility": -999,
- "delta": -999,
- "gamma": -999,
- "theta": -999,
- "vega": -999,
- "rho":   -999,

**request **

```
GET /v1/marketdata/chainsapikey=xxxxxxxxxxx&symbol=FB&contractType=ALL&strikeCount=5&includeQuotes=FALSE&strategy=ANALYTICAL&range=NTM&fromDate=2021-07-10&toDate=2021-07-30&expMonth=ALL&optionType=S HTTP/1.1
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip
    Accept-Language:en-US
    Authorization:Host:
    api.tdameritrade.com
    NS-Proxy-Client-IP:xx.xxx.xxx.xx
    sec-ch-ua:Not;A Brand";v="99
    sec-ch-ua-mobile:?0
    Sec-Fetch-Dest:empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode:cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site:same-site
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML
    X-Forwarded-For:xx.xxx.x.xx
    X-Forwarded-Port:xxxxx
    X-Forwarded-Proto:http
```

**Response sample**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://developer.tdameritrade.com
Access-Control-Max-Age:3628800
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'self'
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 05 Jul 2021 12:52:15 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Application-Context:application:8080
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block
{
  "symbol": "FB",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "underlying": null,
  "strategy": "ANALYTICAL",
  "interval": 0,
  "isDelayed": true,
  "isIndex": false,
  "interestRate": 0.1,
  "underlyingPrice": 354.605,
  "volatility": 29,
  "daysToExpiration": -1,
  "numberOfContracts": 30,
  "callExpDateMap": {
    "2021-07-16:11": {
      "350.0": [
        {
          "putCall": "CALL",
          "symbol": "FB_071621C350",
          "description": "FB Jul 16 2021 350 Call",
          "exchangeName": "OPR",
          "bid": 8.35,
          "ask": 8.55,
          "last": 8.48,
          "mark": 8.45,
          "bidSize": 25,
          "askSize": 23,
          "bidAskSize": "25X23",
          "lastSize": 0,
          "highPrice": 10,
          "lowPrice": 7.5,
          "openPrice": 0,
          "closePrice": 8.47,
          "totalVolume": 1570,
          "tradeDate": null,
          "tradeTimeInLong": 1625255983799,
          "quoteTimeInLong": 1625255999897,
          "netChange": 0.01,
          "volatility": -999,
          "delta": -999,
          "gamma": -999,
          "theta": -999,
          "vega": -999,
          "rho": -999,
          "openInterest": 16040,
          "timeValue": 3.78,
          "theoreticalOptionValue": -1,
          "theoreticalVolatility": 29,
          "optionDeliverablesList": null,
          "strikePrice": 350,
          "expirationDate": 1626465600000,
          "daysToExpiration": 11,
          "expirationType": "R",
          "lastTradingDay": 1626480000000,
          "multiplier": 100,
          "settlementType": " ",
          "deliverableNote": "",
          "isIndexOption": null,
          "percentChange": 0.06,
          "markChange": -0.02,
          "markPercentChange": -0.29,
          "nonStandard": false,
          "mini": false,
          "inTheMoney": true
        }
      ]
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Response from TD Ameritrade on this. Find it totally unacceptable" If you are referring to the Greeks, this is something that we will look to correct after integration with Charles Schwab which we estimate will take 30-36 months.  For your other email around alerts, we do not have an alerts endpoint."

Answer (score 0):

TDAmeritrade Answer- "If you are referring to the Greeks, this is something that we will look to correct after integration with Charles Schwab which we estimate will take 30-36 months.  For your other email around alerts, we do not have an alerts endpoint."